# Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 255

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php, bitbucket

After clone the git repo, install composer and Laravel , this error will come out. Anyone can solve this error?

When I run `laravel new`, I get this error:

```
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
> php artisan optimize
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 255
Application ready! Build something amazing.
```

Answer (score 1):

Which repo you cloned? if you want create a new laravel project, just try run `laravel new projectName`, 
check the doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3#installing-laravel)

Comment: thanks for reply, Ray. i have clone the laravel project. so what should i do?

Comment: @C.Sing, you don't need clone laral project, try read doc. command `Laravel new projectName` will create a new laravel project for you